# An exception to Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

According to Taylor Series, $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}*(x-a)^n $$
However, $\dfrac{1}{x}$,$\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, etc. are not applicable. I tried to do the following:
$$ \dfrac{1}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x)^n $$
Which I assume $a$ is $1$. Now, if $x$ is a positive integer, then a problem exists! The final value of the equation above must also be an integer, yet the answer is impossible to be an integer. Otherwise it is basically true. How come it fails if $x$ is integer?

Of course, the Taylor Series will not work when the function is an error function, such as $\ln x$ (where $x$ is negative).

In what situation will Taylor Series be wrong other than error functions?

Comment: The Taylor series does not need to converge anywhere, if it converges, its radius of convergence is usually relatively small, and where it converges, it need not converge to the function. In your example, you're running against the second point, the radius of convergence is $1$, the series converges only for $0 < x < 2$.

Comment: Do you mean that if the series do not converge, than the series will not be applicable?

Comment: You might study complex analysis to understand the convergence/divergence of Taylor series.

Comment: The series converges when $\large 0 < x < 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Taylor Series of a function:

$f(x) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}c_k (x-a)^k = c_0 + c_1(x-a) + c_2(x-a)^2 + \dots$

The equality holds for $x-a$ in the **radius of convergence**:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{R} = \limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left|c_k\right|^{\large{\frac{1}{k}}}$   (*Cauchy-Hadamard* formula)

where $R$ is the radius of convergence of the given function, or more concretely, the power series converges to the function for all $x$ that satisfies:  $\displaystyle\left|\,x-a\, \right| < R$, where $R\in [0,+\infty]$. $\hspace{1cm}\blacksquare$

---

In your example, for $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, we have:

$\displaystyle f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{a^k}(x-a)^k$

so $\displaystyle c_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{a^k}$.

Now for radius of convergence:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{R} = \limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{|a|^k}} = \frac{1}{|a|} \implies R = |a|.$

So our function is convergent for: $|x-a| < |a|
\Longleftrightarrow \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    0 < x < 2a & \quad \text{for $a>0$}\\
    2a < x < 0 & \quad \text{for $a<0$}
  \end{array} \right.$

Now, you wanted $a = 1$, so our series is convergent for $\displaystyle\boxed{0 < x < 2}$. For all other $x$, the series is divergent.

Comment: A nitpick: You might still get convergence on the boundary of the disk of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

A different way in which a Taylor series can be "wrong" is when a function is not analytic. This statement (when made precise) is more or less the definition of "analytic", but it's helpful to have a word and a concept of analytic being a thing to think about.

In some sense, analytic functions are rare and strange and pretty much nothing is analytic.

But in another, practical, sense, nearly every function you will study turns out to be analytic at any point where it is defined and differentiable.